# Prestashop losing section after login

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm having a weird issue on my prestashop 1.6.

Here is the [SITE](https://montrealimport.com). The site is showing fine but when I log in as a customer, I am losing most links on my nav bar and all the categories on the left is also lost. Nothing in the javascript console, nothing in my php logs.

I decided to look at the cookies and once I deleted the Prestashop-HASH cookie, everything goes back to normal. I then logging in again and there is goes losing the nav and categories again.

All my modules are up-to date and I'm kinda lost.

Answer (score 0):

Did you allow categories by customer groups? When connected are you in a particular customer group?

I think the worry comes from category authorization per customer group.

Regards,

Comment: Awesome! That was it. Thank you very much.